# How to get first row from DB using Entity Framework where column starts with certain string and continues with numeric characters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the first row from the database where the column starts with a certain string and continues with only numeric characters in an ASP.NET MVC application.

The data could look something like this:

```
ABC555, 
ABC111,
EED111,
AB001,
AB002
```

So the problem is that I'm not sure how to get the latest value that starts with AB + numeric values..

I've tried to get the data using Linq:

```
string letterCombination = "AB";
var identifier = db.DATABASE
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Identifier.StartsWith(letterCombination).Identifier;
```

This query could get the rows which also starts with "ABC", which is not what I want.

Any suggestions on how to improve/correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on J.F.'s answer: `Regex.IsMatch` won't translate down to Linq2EF, meaning it first needs to be materialized into memory:

```
var identifier = db.DATABASE
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier)
    .ToList()     // or .AsEnumerable()            
    .FirstOrDefault(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Identifier,"AB[0-9]"));
```

As data sets grow this could get considerably more expensive as it loads *all* rows into memory then takes the first matching one.

This can be combined with your original attempt to limit the # of rows returned:

```
var identifier = db.DATABASE
    .Where(x => x.Identifier.StartsWith(letterCombination))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier)
    .ToList()                 
    .FirstOrDefault(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Identifier, letterCombination+"[0-9]"));
```

It still materializes more rows than needed to memory, but the initial filter should at least keep this to a minimum. When dealing with large objects, it is advisable to project the data down first to just the columns you care about:

```
var identifier = db.DATABASE
    .Where(x => x.Identifier.StartsWith(letterCombination))
    .Select(x => new 
    {  
        x.Id,
        x.Identifier,
        // ... other fields that are needed ..
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier)
    .ToList()                 
    .FirstOrDefault(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Identifier, letterCombination+"[0-9]"));
```

This again reduces the amount of data being loaded into memory if the table was quite large or you need values from related tables, to avoid fetching everything into memory.

If your identifier follows a consistent pattern like always containing 3 digits at the end, then it may be possible to combine the pattern search with a length check:

```
int combinationLength = letterCombination.Length + 3;

var identifier = db.DATABASE
    .Where(x => x.Identifier.StartsWith(letterCombination) && x.Identifier.Length == combinationLength)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: So first you are transferring the complete table to your local process, then you throw away all but one row of the table. Surely this can be optimized? At least limit the transferred data to the rows that start with the "ABC" and then locally use a RegEx to keep only those with only digits.

Comment: Yes, it would be with just the `.AsEnumerable` followed by the RegEx as I warned about that approach. It can be combined with his original attempt to first reduce the set coming back (to elements starting with the desired characters) and reduced again by projecting the table down to the columns needed if it's a particularly large table/graph needed.  It may also be possible to fetch the row by initial letter combination and length *if* the numbering scheme follows a predictable convention. All scenarios were outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) (regular expression) in this way:

```cs
var identifier = db.DATABASE
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Identifier)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Identifier,"AB[0-9]"));
```

This will return the first value beginning with "AB" and following by any number.

Comment: Thanks! This did point me to the right direction. 
But this solution did throw an exception. ```{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}```. But adding ```.AsEnumerable()``` before the regex expression did seem to solve this.

Comment: Caution there though, as using `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` will materialize *all* rows to memory. With a small dataset that cost can be acceptable, but if the # of rows grows over time it is a bit of a landmine.